# I²C bus over PCI

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, device-tree, pci

I am trying to write an ARM driver for a FPGA device connected over PCI.

The FPGA device has some I²C devices and DMA for which I want to write DMA engine driver. The FPGA design is not mine and different I²C devices sit on the same BAR.

I am a bit puzzled on how to do that. It seems to me that the best way would be to make a Multi-Function Driver (MFD) that will load the drivers and assign the memory for each component. I intend to add the the MFD node device tree (as a PCI device), so that I can specify present HW components in there, as well as the DMA channels.

If I add the PCI device to the device tree, how can I get the `struct pci_dev` for my device? Previously using `pci_register_driver()` I get pointer to the `struct pci_dev` in the `.probe()` function.

How do I access the `struct pci_dev` from `platform_driver`'s `.probe()` function?

Is there a way to get it automatically or do in need to find it by vendor and device using, for example, `pci_get_device()`?

Does anyone have a better approach for this?

I have made a node inside PCI node but although compatible driver is present (as module) it did not get loaded:

```dts
pcie@33800000 {
    compatible = "fsl,imx8mm-pcie\0snps,dw-pcie";
    ...
    pci@0,0 {
        compatible = "ccx-qdma";
        device-type = "pci";
    };
};
```

Comment: Yes, one of the good choices is to use MFD model in the Linux kernel. It will be the main PCI device driver you have, on top it will be the number of _function_ device drivers, which will be platform. You may see how, for example, Intel LPSS is done (_drivers/mfd/intel-lpss-pci.c_): it splits device to DMA engine and a SPI/I2C/UART host controller.